# How to set ReCaptcha "en" language in Zend?

Tags: zend-framework, recaptcha

I want to force ReCaptcha form to only use EN language in Zend, however this codes dont work for me:

```
    $recaptcha = new Zend_Service_ReCaptcha($publickey, $privatekey);

    $captcha = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha('captcha',
        array(
            'captcha'       => 'ReCaptcha',
            'captchaOptions' => array('captcha' => 'ReCaptcha', 'service' => $recaptcha, 'lang'=>'en'),
            'ignore' => true
            )
    );

    $this->addElement($captcha);
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

i think this should work (cant test it in the moment, sorry)

```
  $captcha = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha('challenge', array(
            'captcha' => 'ReCaptcha',
                'captchaOptions' => array(
                'captcha' => 'ReCaptcha',
                'privKey' => ' ',
                'pubKey' => ' '
            )
    ));

    $captcha->getCaptcha()->getService()
            ->setOption('theme', 'white')
            ->setOption('lang', 'en'); // should do it
```

Comment: Hi @ArneRie, thanks for the response mate! However i already tried that code but still not working. No choice for me but to disect ReCaptcha codes from  the Zend core Service library. I just found that zend will load ReCaptcha js from google CDN:

http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

and the lang will be automatically translated based on the user's location. I appended '&lang=en' on the url and it works well now.